# 404 error on Plunker for Angular2 code?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, systemjs, plunker

```
    Please check this plunk link

   I am 404 error, I am unable to find it , please anyone can solve it, and update my plunk
```

Here the link https://plnkr.co/edit/rKxWDg?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your `base href` is path invalid for plunker

> A live coding environment like Plunker sets the application base
>   address dynamically so you can't specify a fixed address. That's why
>   the example code replaces the  with a script that writes
>   the  tag on the fly.

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

> You should only need this trick for the live example, not production
>   code.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#set-the-lt-base-href-

2) If you want to use `DynamicDetail` component within `AppComponent` template you have to export it from y`BusinessModule`

3) You need to add `router-outlet` within `DynamicDetail` template

**[Modified plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QHjOTz?p=preview)**